# Azure Data Factory Copy Activity Pipeline Destination Mapping String Format Date to Sql Date column Warning

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am doing copy activity to load the data from azure data factory to on premise SQL table.
I could see in copy activity column Mapping, there is warning message like source column is string with date and time value (`2022-09-13 12:53:28`) so that i created target SQL table column is date data type.

While import mapping in copy activity, i could see the whatever date column i mapped in SQL. there is warning message throwing in ADF. kindly advise, how do we resolve it.

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I have tried the same. You can ignore the warning and run the pipeline. It would run successfully and insert the values. When there is a valid string with data that is additional i.e., more that that is accepted by the datetime field, then data would be truncated

Comment: is it possible to resolve that warning. if yes, please give me a note or some example. thanks.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do so. I think it is just a generic warning the ADF is giving while copying data from file to a table indicating that if the target table column gets a field value more than it is required, then that source data field value will be truncated. When I insert [this data](https://i.imgur.com/o1BBw0w.png), the final table data will be as shown in [this image](https://i.imgur.com/nZuXfPd.png)

Comment: @karthikelavan it is just a warning yu can try to debug and check whether you are getting the correct output in the target tables

Answer (score 0):

The warning just indicates that it `copy data` will truncate source column data when additional data information is found in a column value. There would not be any error in this case but there might be data loss.

[image]

- In your case, since the column value is `2022-09-13 12:53:28`, it will be inserted without any issue into the `datetime` column without truncation.
- The following is a demonstration where I try to insert the following source data:

```
id,first_name,date
1,Wenona,2022-09-13 12:53:28
2,Erhard,2022-09-13 13:53:28
3,Imelda,2022-09-13 14:53:28
```

- The copy activity runs successfully and inserts the data. The following is my target table data after inserting:

[image]

- When I insert the following data, it would be truncated to just include a precision of 2 digits of milli seconds as shown below.

```
id,first_name,date
1,Wenona,2022-09-13 12:53:28.11111
2,Erhard,2022-09-13 13:53:28.11111
3,Imelda,2022-09-13 14:53:28.11111
```

[image]